# Linux parallel copy from one source to multi destinations with a progress output

Tags: bash, rsync, gnu-parallel

I'm trying to parallel copy one large dataset (~7TB) to three external USB drives at the same time. Ideally I want to be able to kick it off, leave it to crack on and come back to check on it every so often.

I understand that it may not be the quickest way to do it, but I really don't want to have to go back to swap drives over and take 2 days to do it.

Here's where I've got to:

parallel --bar rsync ./source/ -r --info=progress2 ::: /dest/one/ /dest/two/

Which works, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get a good readout. There are plenty of parallel copying of one dataset for speed, but my limitation is the USB HDD write speed, which is about 200MBps.

I'm absolutely open to suggestions that throw the current idea in the bin.

***EDIT***

The command I ended up with thanks to Renaud is:

parallel -u rsync ./source/ -r --info=progress2{2} {1} ::: /dest/one/ /dest/two/

Which gives me a progress report of one of the threads which isn't perfect for all applications, but is great for this one!

Comment: "_my limitation is the USB HDD write speed, which is about 200MBps_": are you trying to exceed this limitation?

Comment: Hiya, no it's just a consideration, by having the disks written in parallel I hope to minimise the interaction.

Comment: OK, I was a bit confused by this statement. So your issue is only with the progress output. As you wrote your script each `rsync` reports about its own progress. I don't know what it looks like but I imagine that it is not what you want. Why not asking for the progress of only one of the `rsync` jobs and not asking for progress of `parallel` (no `--bar`)? Of course, if the selected job is faster than the others, the progress will stop before the end, but if your drives are about the same it should still be useful.

Comment: Something like: `parallel rsync ./source/ -r --info=progress{2} {1} ::: /dest/one/ /dest/two/ :::+ 2 0`.

Comment: Deleting the --bar just gives me no progress report until it's done. I'm happy to just have one progress report from one of the threads but I can't make it tell me as it goes. Let me try that!

Comment: Did you try the `-u` option of `parallel`?

Comment: Nope it just leaves me hanging until the end and then gives me a 100%

Comment: Legend! -u fixes it

Answer (score 0):

> Which works, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get a good readout.

Is progress information of each `rsync` what you are asking for?

In that case try:

```
parallel --ll --tag rsync ./source/ -r --info=progress2 ::: /dest/one/ /dest/two/
```

Requires version 20220522 or later.